# Getting table id with repecive data using database table in java or android

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, shuffle

I have following structure figured table which name **student**. [image]

Here, I want to shuffle these data according to its first column **id**, **with receptive their data**. I have try this code:

```
   public void shuffleStudent(int[] ar) {

    Random rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = ar.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        int index = rnd.nextInt(i + 1);
        // Simple swap
        int a = ar[index];
        ar[index] = ar[i];
        ar[i] = a;
    }
}
```

and getting from this

```
int [] t= db.shuffleJokes(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("id")));
```

or

```
Cursor cur = db.shuffleJokes(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("id")));
```

**But** these two could not work. And problem this type

```
The method shuffleJokes(int[]) in the type DatabaseHelper is not applicable for the arguments (String)
```

My question is if my `suffleStudent` function is correct or not, if correct. So how to get in `suffleStudent.java`. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

your shuffle-function looks fine, but sending in a string when the function expects an array of int doesn't make sense.  I guess `cur` is a database cursor.  You need to read the entire database in to an array, then pass this array to the shuffle-function.

A completely different approach is to add a new colum to the database table, put a random number in this colums for each record, and the select order by this column.  This would do the shuffeling in the database rather than in your code, which would probably be faster.  (You probably need an index though)